# Use Filezilla as file manager

Tags: filezilla, doublecmd

At the moment for managing files I need to switch between Double Commander and Filezilla.

Is it possible to use Filezilla not only as FTP client but also as file manager? To use left and right panel to managing local files?

Comment: What about the other way round, using Double Commander as an FTP client?

Comment: @Melebius I don't much like Double Commander. But I like Filezilla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FileZilla is only an FTP / SFTP client.  It does not have the capability to be a File Manager like Double Commander can do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible since Filezilla is an FTP/SFTP client and seems to only accept local-remote and remote-local calls